# .htaccess rewrite rule fix query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am new to .htaccess and need something very simple, but i cannot seem to get it to work.
I have have an .htacces file already and mod_rewrite enabled.
I have tried several examples:

```
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} detail/(\d+) [NC]
#RewriteRule ^/detail/$ bestride.com/detail.php?id=%1 [L,R=301]
```

i have a url like this example.com/detail/23342343243432

i need to rewrite to example.com/detail.php?id=23342343243432

Just for the moment
How Do i do this.

Thanks

Comment: You actually want to redirect the browser to the `detail.php?id=123234` URL, or rewrite it silently so the end user only sees `detail/12323` ?

Comment: i need to actually redirect to detail.php/id=1234234

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(detail)/(.*)$  detail.php?id=$2
```

Comment: When editing a code block, you can indent 4 spaces, or highlight it and `ctl-k` or click the `{}` button, cheers.

Comment: thats very close but i need the url to be            example.com/detail.php?id=123. I need a redirect i believe

Comment: nm i got. i needed this RewriteRule ^(detail)/(.*)$  detail.php?id=$2 [L,R=301]